JDBC SSL connection to RDS Postgres allowed although no certificate exists in Truststore
I have Postgres RDS database in AWS configured with the rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 certificate.
In my Java application I use the following connection URL:
jdbc:postgresql://my-db-name.ajsa891hjkdas.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb?searchpath=dataset?ssl=true&sslmode=require

At the application startup I set the JVM properties:
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=app/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass

In the truststore I have currently only Amazon Root CA, but no rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 imported.
However, the connection seems to be working, although I would expect it to fail due to the missing certificate.
Why is the connection working, although I did not import any RDS certificate in my Truststore? What should I do in order to properly configure the SSL connection?
Thank you in advance!
I expect working SSL connection between my Java application and RDS.

Figured it out - the connection is encrypted, although we do not verify the RDS certificate. This is due to the "require" ssl mode. "require" is not the same as "verify-full" or "verify-ca", which would additionally check if the certificate provided by the RDS is trusted, using the truststore of our application.
"require" will allow the encrypted connection to be established even if we don't validate the RDS certificate.
Link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html
